# Conversion php string to array

Tags: java, php, arrays

I use PHP (via ajax) to retrieve data and use it in java. I intend to use the information Google Chart. Example below:

(1) PHP output / input in java

```
[[8058, 26.4]/[8081, 26.5]/[8091, 26.5]/[8092, 26.5]/[8094, 26.5]/[8096, 26.5]/[8104, 26.6]/[8109, 26.6]/[8120, 26.6]/]
```

(2) I converted the above PHP to an string array - looks as follow:

```
[8058, 26.4],[8081, 26.5],[8091, 26.5],[8092, 26.5],[8094, 26.5],[8096, 26.5],[8104, 26.6],[8109, 26.6],[8120, 26.6]
```

(3) However it must be converted into an array which can be read by Google Charts. The following array I can successfully read in Google Charts

```
p2 = ([[5, 23.8],[6, 24.0],[7, 24.1],[8, 24.2],[9, 24.3]]);
```

So how to convert (2) to an array which can be read by Google Charts? I am not an java expert and am kind of stuck here ... any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Convert your array into a JSON string. Everything understand a JSON data structure

Answer (score 0):

```
[8058, 26.4],[8081, 26.5],[8091, 26.5],[8092, 26.5],[8094, 26.5],[8096, 26.5],[8104, 26.6],[8109, 26.6],[8120, 26.6] 
$data = [8058, 26.4]@[8081, 26.5]@[8091, 26.5]@[8092, 26.5]@[8094, 26.5]@[8096, 26.5]@[8104, 26.6]@[8109, 26.6]@[8120, 26.6]
This string change comma separated values by other character like @ after that execute below function.
print_r(explode ( '@' , $data));
**OUTPUT:**
array (
  0 => '[8058, 26.4]',
 1 => '[8081, 26.5]',
 2 => '[8091, 26.5]',
 3 => '[8092, 26.5]',
 4 => '[8094, 26.5]',
 5 => '[8096, 26.5]',
 6 => '[8104, 26.6]',
 7 => '[8109, 26.6]',
 8 => '[8120, 26.6]',
)
```

Comment: How would you "export" this data to java and use it in the javascript?

Comment: just return data from php to jquery in json format and pass data in graphs as per graph format.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback and suggestions / not sure how the above can be integrated into my code (explode does not work).

I am also looking at JSON / but first want to get this off my plate.

My lines below:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={
    'modules':[{
        'name':'visualization',
        'version':'1.1',
        'packages':['corechart']
    }]
}"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('number', 'X');
        data.addColumn('number', 'temp');

        p2 = ([[5, 23.8],[6, 24.0],[7, 24.1],[8, 24.2],[9, 24.3]]); //Test array to check Google Line Chart -> works

        // Retrieve data via  php       
        var phpData = $.ajax({
            url: "test.php",
            dataType: "text",
            async: false
        }).responseText;

        var ary = phpData.replace('[[','[').replace('/]','').split('/');

        data.addRows(p2);       // This works to draw line chart (test array P2)

        var options = {
            title: 'Any',
            curveType: 'function',
            legend: { position: 'bottom' },
            hAxis: { title: 'Time', logScale: false },
            vAxis: { title: 'T', logScale: false },
            colors: ['#a52714', '#097138']
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>
    <div id="curve_chart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Solved it - created some loops to correct data and parsed the string to floats. It works and next steps is to go with JSON :-). Thanks